# How can i hide MPMoviePlayer controls?

Tags: mpmovieplayer

i want put a movie at my application starting   but i want hide the movie controls like (stop , play , next and ... ) here is my code :

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>



-(void)viewDidLoad
{
     NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
     NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"myvideo" ofType:@"mp4"];
     NSURL *movieURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];
     MPMoviePlayerController *IntroMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
     [IntroMovie play];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i figured it out.

Code:

```
IntroMovie.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do `IntroMovie.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;`

Since .movieControlMode was deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

**In Objective-C**

```
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```

**In Swift**

```
 moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
```